# animate only one item at any one time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am animating five boxes on click. They basically go up and down. Only one item or box should animate at any one time. This is fine, until you click multiple times, multiple boxes very quickly, then the behaviour becomes erratic.

i have created a demo link here http://jsfiddle.net/fLmt6/9/

The code below is responsible for the bounce animation

```
var itemActive = $(".items li.active");                

var indicator = 1;            

bounceItem();

function bounceItem() {        
    bounceInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (indicator === 1) {
            indicator = -1;
        } else {
            indicator = 1;
        }
        $(".items li").not(".active").stop().css({
            top: "11px"
        });
        itemActive.animate({
            top: "+=" + (indicator * 11)
        }, 400);

    }, 400);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Firstly, delegate the event to a parent element. Here, I'll use the body as I don't know the structure of your wider HTML. Event delegation is good advice generally and comes with several benefits, one being that you can filter elements when the event fires, not when it is registered. Which leads me to...

2) Add a filter that ignores clicks to any boxes that are already animated.

So change

```
var item = $(".items ul li a");
item.click(function () {
```

to

```
$('body').on('click', '.items li:not(:animated) a', function() {
```

Comment: @gables20 sometimes two boxes jump at the same time. Even though I optimize code and fix the error with `bounceInterval`: http://jsfiddle.net/fLmt6/12/ Ehm, no, I broke something. Needs to look

Comment: This is due to where you set your created your bounce interval..i updated your code http://jsfiddle.net/fLmt6/13/

Comment: @gables20 yea, I have already placed it there in http://jsfiddle.net/fLmt6/11/ and got it back in http://jsfiddle.net/fLmt6/14/, but still sometimes there are problems

Comment: @Regent, what sort of problems are you seeing, from my end, its just the jerkyness so far.

Comment: @gables20 I still get two bouncing boxes at the same time in my version of Fiddle. Maybe it's better to forbid clicking while the previous one is setting up... Or maybe the problem still persists in setting and clearing intervals

Answer (score 0):

You can add new variable, which will check, if the element has been animated. You need animate it twice - TOP, then BOTTOM. So I was edited your code.

Variable `animated` is set to `0` before animation, then set to `1` when element bounce on top and then set to `2` when it bounce back to bottom, then stop the bouncing.

```
var item = $(".items ul li a");

item.click(function () {

$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
$(this).parent().siblings().css({
    top: "11px"
});

if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {

    $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast", function () {

        $(this).addClass("active").fadeIn("slow");

        var itemActive = $(".items li.active");
        var indicator = 1;

        var animated = 0;
        bounceItem();

        function bounceItem() {
            bounceInterval = setInterval(function () {
                if (indicator === 1) {
                    indicator = -1;
                } else {
                    indicator = 1;
                }
                $(".items li").not(".active").stop().css({
                    top: "11px"
                });
                if(animated != 2) {
                    itemActive.animate({
                        top: "+=" + (indicator * 11),
                        times: 1
                    }, 400);
                    animated += 1;
                }

            }, 400);
        }

    });           

    clearInterval(bounceInterval);
}

});
```

**[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fLmt6/10/)**

Comment: this changes the functionality a bit. the box should keep bouncing..until you click another. but yours bounces once.

Comment: I thought it was what you asking for .. eh, sorry, my bad